# How to transfer uneditable data with form with colander/deform (pyramid)

Tags: python, deform, colander

I have a small series of forms. The first accepts two fields, a record ID and an institution ID which need to be passed onto the next form as static information, but needs to be passed together with the rest of the data from the second form which then uses the data from both forms to do the real work. I have marked the first as readonly=true and the other is a select that I am disabling via javascript. When I click "Submit" both return validation errors as missing.

What is the colander approach to do this? I want the values to be visible on the form, so hiddenfield isn't quite right.

Comment: Is it ok to use session data? I just store everything in pyramid_redis in similar scenario, as hidden fields are complicated.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it feels wrong. I'm coming from the Rails world, and hidden fields work beautifully for capturing data from previous forms or from GET parameters.